# get Working Copy object

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

Can someone post the code necessary to get the private working copy ID or object from an object that has been checked out previously? I tried to use Alfresco web Scripts to get the working copy, like this: 
/alfresco/service/cmis/pwc/i/d1f91b65-1165-4db5-8521-8fc3abb1074b
but it gave me a 404

any help please

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually trying to do? Alfresco will happily let you get to Working Copy objects, and CMIS supports accessing them too, but without details of what you want to do and what you've tried we can't help you much!

Comment: How I can get Through OpenCMIS working copy object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using OpenCMIS, the getAllVersions() call returns all versions of the object, including the Private Working Copy (PWC) if the object is checked out. The PWC will be on the top of the list followed by the latest version.

So, in your case, if you want to do a query for the object, or navigate through the folder tree, or whatever, you can do that. Then ask the object for its versions and you can get the PWC from that list if it is checked out.

Here's a Groovy example:

```
document = session.getObjectByPath('/versionableExample.txt')
println("Checked out?" + document.versionSeriesCheckedOut)
versions = document.getAllVersions()
for (version in versions) {
    println ("Version:" + version.versionLabel + " PWC?:" + version.privateWorkingCopy)
}
```

This outputs the following assuming a document called versionableExample.txt exists in the root of the Apache Chemistry In-Memory repo that has three versions and is currently checked out:

```
Checked out?true
Version:V 4.0 PWC?:true
Version:V 3.0 PWC?:false
Version:V 2.0 PWC?:false
Version:V 1.0 PWC?:false
```

Hope that helps,

Jeff

Answer (score 2):

The property cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId should contain the PWC id if the document is checked out. Here is an OpenCMIS snippet:

```
String pwcId = doc.getVersionSeriesCheckedOutId();
Document pwc = (Document) session.getObject(pwcId);
```

Comment: Thanks All for your answers it was helping

Answer (score 1):

I guess your answer is in [this](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cmis-acl-problemquestion-solved-12052012-0759) forum post.

I'll recap shortly:

```
RepositoryInfo repositoryInfo = session.getRepositoryInfo();
AclCapabilities aclCapabilities = repositoryInfo.getAclCapabilities();
Map<String, PermissionMapping> permissionMappings = aclCapabilities.getPermissionMapping();
PermissionMapping permissionMapping = permissionMappings.get(PermissionMapping.CAN_CHECKOUT_DOCUMENT);

List<String> permissions = permissionMapping.getPermissions();

Ace addAce = session.getObjectFactory().createAce(principal, permissions);
List<Ace> addAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
addAces.add(addAce);

document.addAcl(addAces, AclPropagation.REPOSITORYDETERMINED);
ObjectId checkedOutDocumentObjectId = document.checkOut();

Document checkedOutDocument = (Document) session.getObject(checkedOutDocumentObjectId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay 
but i could bring the privet working Object in this code 
because in code you still the pwc instance 
in my case i want to get the working  copy by query or any other way to get the pwc from here parent ID 
any idea ??

Comment: Ofcourse you can query. You need to checkout the Document, then go to the NodeBrowser en probably there is a new type created or a new aspect placed. You can use that to query it and use the path of the parent. Or use the children service of the parent folder and loop through and check on name. Because the name is always main document + (working copy).